# How do I convert series to string in order to use the apply function with .contains function in python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, series

## sample data - I am reading this in from a CSV

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'Long Title' : 
              Stand-Up: "Weird Al" Yankovic, Stand-Up: "Weird Al",Yankovic HD,
               Rampage4Real: Opening Round,
               Rampage4Real: Opening Round HD,
               Hashtag Wars S1,
               Hashtag Wars S1 HD,
               Best of Season})
```

## I want to apply this function to a series to create a new series with parsed values:

```
   def func(value):
        if value.str.contains(":"):
            return value

data["LongTitleAdjusted"] = data["Long Title"].apply(func)
```

---

I'm gettting this error:

```
  AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'str'
```

So I've been trying to convert the series to a string data type, but keep getting this error even when I "ignore" when encoding:

```
 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Do you have the quotes right where you define `data`?

Comment: If the `dtype` of that column is `str` then you can just do `data['LongTitleAdjusted'] = data.loc[data['Long Title'].str.contains(':'), data['Long Title']]`

Comment: Yes, i do.  Sorry I am not actually using the dataframe above -- just an example to see what the data looks like. No errors on dataframe itself just when I try to parse through it

Comment: The dtype is an object -- I can't seem to convert it to a string

Comment: That means it could be `str` that is just the `np` representation for python objects, try what I suggested to see if it works